# openFrameworks / freeimage.a cause error with ios arm 64

Tags: ios, objective-c, openframeworks, arm64, freeimage

i'm using assimp.a and freeimage.a with voufria ar   base on 
https://github.com/DrNeuroSurg/REVu/tree/master/REVU_IOS 
 I'm trying to build an app I've been working on for 64-bit iOS and it's failing at the linker. The error is this:

ld: 128-bit LDR/STR not 16-byte aligned: from __ZN13CResizeEngine16horizontalFilterEP8FIBITMAPjjjjPK10tagRGBQUADS1_j (0x1006FFF20) to l005@0x00000850 (0x100B825D8) in '__ZN13CResizeEngine16horizontalFilterEP8FIBITMAPjjjjPK10tagRGBQUADS1_j' from /Users/xxxxx/Desktop/sharq_final/El-shareq/AR/QCAR/REVU_IOS/FreeImage/lib/ios/freeimage.a(Resize.o-arm64) for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 Anybody run across something like this while porting to 64-bit (or ever)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to a clash of clangs. FreeImage.a was built with the latest clang from Xcode 6.3.1.

Make sure you have the latest Xcode Installed. 
Do a clean, restart your Mac and try again.

The only reference I could find similar to this issue was at this link, and it was solved with these steps:
http://www.politepix.com/forums/topic/linked-errors-with-openears-iphone-5s/

I have posted an issue on the openFrameworks github as well with some more information:
https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues/3984